# JS function is not working in .js file but working when written inside .html file

Tags: javascript, html

**Working**

```
.html
<body>
    <a href="#" id="abc">
        
    </a>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "abc";
</script>
```

**Not working**

```
.html
<script defer src="function.js"></script>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="abc" onload="abc()">
        
    </a>
</body>

.js
function abc() {
  document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "abc";
}
```

What is the problem with the code? I couldn't figure out and hope someone can answer my question

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Using an `onload` on a fragment identifier anchor doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the onload to the body.

If there is no problem with your js file path, it will work.

```
<body onload="abc()">
    <a href="#" id="abc"></a>
</body>
```